# How can I configure SSL certificates on Digital Ocean server to host ReactJS app connecting to GoLang server on the same Droplet?

Tags: networking, ssl, load-balancer, letsencrypt, digital-ocean

I am hosting a chess application website on a Digital Ocean Droplet.

On the server, I am serving up a static React app using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). I am also running a GoLang server with a single Websocket endpoint as the backend. So these two servers are on the same droplet i.e. same IP address.

There is a load balancer forwarding HTTPS to HTTP using an SSL certificates generated via Digital Ocean's Lets Encrypts integration.

The site works well on Chrome (see [tonycodes.com](https://tonycodes.com)). However, on mobile phones and Safari web browser, I get an error.

Safari's web inspector returns this error when attempting to connect with the Golang server websocket:

```
WebSocket network error: OSStatus Error -9807: Invalid certificate chain
```

These are the load balancer settings:

[image: Load Balancer Screenshot]

The GoLang websocket endpoint is on port 8081. The React frontend is on port 80.

I am not familiar with SSL encryption certificate chain rules that I may be breaking with this setup. Any help is very much appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: There’s only one rule: Send all the certificates all the time. Your Go application is probably not sending some intermediate certificate.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB. The Golang application is behind the same load balancer as the frontend and is sending the same certificate that it provides for the frontend port.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to connect to `wss://157.230.65.223:8081/uci`. But your server's certificate wasn't issued for "157.230.65.223" – it was issued for "tonycodes.com". This mismatch between the requested URL and the received certificate *always* causes a critical failure in the TLS connection, as doing otherwise would bypass one of the main TLS security measures.

Change your websocket URL to `wss://tonycodes.com:8081/uci`.

Comment: THANK YOU! That fixed the problem. So simple now that you bring the answer. I really appreciate the help.